# What is the ideal structure of tables for Spark to work with (Tall vs Wide)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I've been trying to think about what the ideal table structure would be for the fastest Spark queries.

I'll try and provide a use case: Let's say your gathering stats for every car in the world and you want to use calculate various metrics with basic math (i.e. add, sub, mult, div).

Would be better to structure the data in a tall table with minimal fields like: day, metric, type, value?

Or would it be better to build a wide tables, that may store metrics independently. With more fields like: day, emmision_value, tire_pressure_value, speed_value, weight_value, heat_value, radio_value, etc .

Is it right to say that tall tables are better for spark? I assume it would be less memory intensive with a taller table.

Comment: Has nothing to do with spark, is a generic question.

Comment: I disagree, not every processing engine handles things like partitioning and clustering the same way, so someone with an in depth knowledge of spark could probably point out pros and cons of table structure.

Comment: @tylercomp 1) I don't think your above comment is appreciating whoever had looked at your question 2) AFAIK thebluephantom does have a depth knowledge of Spark. You of course can disagree but there are many different way to say so. 3) Spark is designed to read data in **any** scale (horizontally and vertically), so it's doesn't really matter in most cases. 4) the data you stored underlay has a major impact to what you're asking here, like is it columnair or row-based etc

Comment: 4) there are **many** ways to improve Spark reading process, from API to configuration, data size, partitioning, etc. Storing data wide vs tall is more likely a logic question, as which way is more convenient for your consumer app

Comment: ah, @thebluephantom, I did not mean to imply you did not have a depth of knowledge - just that I was looking for this question specifically in context of Spark.

Comment: I’m not indulted but ig is a point for all databases. Look at hbsse the premise is wide column families.

Comment: @pltc, thank you, I guess to add more context, this question would come before storing the underlaying data.  Like in a world where you have to use Spark, how would you store it, prior to being processed by spark.  I guess the reality of most spark implementations is that it is really used the other way around, where spark is configured around an existing data asset.  

I still feel there are likely best ways to store data, and maybe if I added more context like I want to use the cheapest fastest solution.  From all that I've read so far tall tables seem preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a subjective question not exactly related to spark, but I'll try and answer none the less.

> I assume it would be less memory intensive with a taller table.

Not really, the amount of storage required should be the same in either case based on the use case you have mentioned so let's get this out of the way. In case of taller tables there more rows and lesser columns and in case of wide tables the opposite. So on a cell level it should roughly be the same. I'm considering un compressed data independent of storage format.

Now lets talk about the mentioned use case. Simply put, it's aggregations. This may be fed downstream or may be used for reporting. Generally keeping this is mind, wider tables/views are better simply because - Lesser rows per day = less I/O as less shuffle.

Having said that, look through the cons below as well,

1. Schema evolution problems due to fixed schema
2. more suited for batch processing

Taller tables will be more streaming friendly, easier to extend for additional metrics and if its used with a source that supports push down, can result in quick partial scans.

in short, it very much depends on your operations.